# Invisible re-captcha fully from javascript without form submission

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I am trying to use an invisible re-captcha v2 on a form that is submitted through JS. Every example I see online shows a regular plain HTML submitted form with a specified action and method, but I am using `preventDefault()` on my form to submit it with ajax. It seems like such a simple thing but I've been searching for hours and can't find a single person online who has ever done this.

HMTL:

```
<form id="form-login">
  <!-- ...form fields... -->

  <div
      class="g-recaptcha"
      data-sitekey="<site_key>"
      data-size="invisible"
    ></div>
  <button class="uk-button uk-button-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#form-login').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  console.log(grecaptcha.getResponse()); // <-- always comes back empty
});
```

I can see that the captcha is initializing because I can see the icon in the bottom right.

I've seen `grecaptcha.execute()` but it doesn't seem to do anything for me.

There are no errors in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I had a problem like you, making captcha invisible created a lot of issues for me e.g. https://github.com/google/recaptcha/issues/269 which is still an opened issue on GitHub.

I solved it with dynamically genarated captcha on each time form is submitted. Here is a bit of code I used. (commented code is a call to backend to verify response with Google API).

https://gist.github.com/ANTOSzbk/75ed7003e914162550f61399122a3bd4

Then you just use my function like this:

```js
$('#form-login').submit(async function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const response = await captchaVerification();
  if (response) { } // proper submit code execution
  else { } // on invalid captcha response
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That seems to work! I just had to add the `size: 'invisible'` option to the render and call `grecaptcha.execute()` after rendering. However I'm a little confused as to why this works. Isn't the point of the invisible captcha that it sits on the page to monitor mouse movements to detect if you're a bot? If I'm creating the captcha and immediately sending it how can it get a accurate reading?

Comment: Actually no. Captcha is one time executed thing, and reCAPTCHA v2 particularly is advanced captcha which gives you very simple task on the start, but after it detects multiple requests from same address it starts to complicate its tasks. It does not collect any other information from your website. It just gives you response if the captcha was successfully solved by the user, you can do everything about it.